# Designing student monitoring sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to design a monitoring Excel sheet to keep track of my students' progress.
It should look something like this:

[image: student tracking tool]

1. In the example picture, I'd be interested in assessing each student's performance in a said exercise for their reading competence in English. For example, if Marine got in (p.24 ex 1) a score of 5/8, it should appear like that, but also with colour change (see point 2).
2. However, I'm also interested in the colour actually CHANGING when the student obtains half or more (the cell turning into green if they obtain 4/8 or more than that); alternatively, the cell turning into red if they get less than that (3/8, f.e.)

I got the template from [here (XLS file)](http://euitt.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Skills-Matrix-Template.xls).
I was wondering how I could change the settings in order to get the desired result.

Comment: *if Marine got in (p.24 ex 1) a score of 5/8, it should appear like that* Intersection cell between the column of `Marine` and row of `p.24 ex 1` contains nevertheless `4`... are you sure in your words ""like that"? *the colour actually CHANGING when the student obtains half or more* There is NO data in your table with the value `8` which must be used for to calculate. The task is unsolvable. *... the cell turning into green if ... alternatively, the cell turning into red* use conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Conditional Formats` on the home tab just to the left of the Table Formatter and Styles Gallery.

Generally speaking it it is best to think of each cell as a discrete unit that cannot be divided.  Just like what you've done with your template.  Sometimes though, a softer look is desired where colors blend across cell boundaries.  Or maybe a situation calls for symbols that appear next to your data instead of changing the cell color.

`Conditional Formatting` can do this with ease..  For your purpose, it is as simple as selecting the range you want to format, selecting an effect (perhaps a 3 color green to yellow to red gradient), and how the data should be evaluated (above and below a number, highest and lowest numbers, etc.)

There are a lot of visually appealing effects that are predefined and easily customized.  Choosing your favorite may be the hardest part. 
If none of the predefined options are appealing then you may want to create your own formats by changing colors, borders, patterns, and more.

Answer (score 0):

This can be acomplished in Excel:

1. Go to Home Tab.
2. Select the area you want to format. In your case Area is "C4:L7".
3. Select "CONDITIONAL FORMATTING" from the Menu.
4. Select "NEW RULE".
5. Select " From Only Cells that contain value.
6. From Drop Down Tabs select : " Cell Value " , " Equal to" , 0 "
7. Format as you want Colour, Fill etc. say RED. The job is done. Now follow the same procedure, same steps  again and for value 1 select say Yellow Colour. Same for 2, 3, 4 etc. For other sheet and many other Reports, you can then apply  " FORMAT PAINTER " to get the same results.

Comment: Don't use format painter to propagate conditional formatting rules. This is tremendously slow and unwieldy.

Comment: @HarshadAmichandVega - Please keep the unnecessary comments like "Thanks", "Regards", "Merry Christmas", and anything that is considered noise out of your answers in the future.  They are not necessary.